# Auto-Populate Field based on Content Type Form Selected

Tags: list, content-type, wss-3.0

In WSS3.0, we are creating a list where there will be 3 different content types - or forms - to select from and fill out. Because of this, we have a field to select the type of request the user is making.

However, we want to make it so that this field is auto-selected based on the form the user selects. That way they can't select a form to make a certain request, change their mind, and select another option once in the form.

Is there a way to do this without code? Or should we base this off the title and create a workflow that if the title contains "request 1", etc etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think workflow is not a good option.

You can do it with code.

Without code you can do that:

- Create three fields instead of one
- Asign each field to each content type

For instance: field 1 to content type 1, field 2 to CT2, field 3 to CT3.

Answer (score 0):

In the edit form you could hide the "Change content type" selector - it would not be completely bullit proof, but from my experience it Works quite well.

Each content type has a different url when you create them, so you're pretty covered there.

Comment: Thank you. The main thing I should've mentioned in the post though is we want to send emails based on the request opened to do certain things. Say, request 1 only needs to send an email to open a ticket. Request 2 needs to send an email to open a ticket also, but send an email to multiple distribution lists as well. Because of this, we were going to use a workflow. If a specific field said it was Request type 1, send email only to open a ticket. If that field said Request type 2, send email to open ticket but also email other distros.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, the workflow should be able to use the content type in an "if" statement.

Comment: And I can set that to the content type? I had no idea that was possible - I  thought you could only compare fields in the list as a whole. I'll take a look - thanks!

Comment: In the workflow yes. If you create 3 different content types and then have one workflow trigger on change of the item and then simple look at what content type the item is you have have it do 3 completely different Things.